# Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException The file or directory to be published does not exist: /frontend/web

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

Переносил сайт с одного сервера на другой с базой данных postgresql. 
Базу подключил. Выполнил команду

```
composer install
```

При загрузке сайта выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Команду `yii init` выполнили?

Comment: Выполнил php init, выбрал "production", и везде "no" прописал, кроме "Initialize the application under 'Production' environment?" Команды yii init не существует. Не помогает.

Comment: А папка `frontend/web` и файл `index.php` существует?

Comment: Конечно. index.php лежит в  frontend/web

Comment: А почему вы не стали переписывать все данные при выполнении команды `init`? Может проблема в этом.

Comment: Потому что с этой командой весь конфиг перезапишется, и все остальное тоже. Я как понял это нужно для первоначальной установки. А у меня сайт уже готовый, его нужно только перенести

Comment: Эта утилита не только заменяет файлы, так же она устанавливает права на запись некоторых папок и файлов. По сути выполнение команды `init` должен проходить безболезненно, что касается секретных данных, типа логин и пароль к БД, то их можно хранить в переменных окружения или другой способ хранения. Как вариант можно попробовать запустить `init` с перезаписью всего, а потом вернуть конфиги обратно